# Getting ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an error

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

while running this query:

```
WITH Dups AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, AMOUNT, BATCH_ID, PROCESS_DATE, ITEM_NUMBER, ERROR_TYPE, INSERTED_DATE, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, ERROR_TYPE ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM 
        ERROR_TABLE
    WHERE
        inserted_date >= TRIM(TO_DATE('01-AUG-17', 'DD-MON-YY')) 
        AND inserted_date <= TRIM(TO_DATE('11-AUG-17', 'DD-MON-YY'))
)
DELETE FROM Dups 
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: you can't delete rows from a cte, so they must be followed by a select. Maybe you want to wrap this in a subquery and where clause for your RN > 1 condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how to delete duplicates in Oracle.  Inspired, but not for that database.  Something like this:

```
delete error_table et
    where et.inserted_date >= date '2017-08-01' and
          et.inserted_date <= date '2017-08-11' and
          rowid > (select min(et2.rowid)
                   from error_table et2
                   where et2.inserted_date >= date '2017-08-01' and
                         et2.inserted_date <= date '2017-08-11' and
                         et2.id = et.id and
                         et2.error_type = et.error_type
                  );
```